# Table cell overflow-y scroll, with absolute divs inside it

Tags: html, css

I need table cell with some fix defined height to be overflow-y scroll when it has many absolute divs inside it.

Here is my html code:

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It's all about calendar plugin which has table cells with these divs positioned absolute.
I can give cell height to be e.g. 150px but can't make it be overflow-y scroll.

Any help?

Comment: Table cell don't take position attribute (you might get away with it in some browsers, but not all)

Comment: A link to the calendar plugin and your css could be helpfull.

Comment: BTW you dont need the `<br />` tag as <div> are displayed `block` by default

Comment: It's impossible to give calendar code and following css, but you can image it like this fiddle code here (http://jsfiddle.net/shix/24XgW/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div to wrap your divs then style it

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mX6g6/3/)

```
.content{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#ccc;

}


<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="content">    
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="content">    
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
            <div class="divs">test</div><br/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```